# Как парсить данные с wildberries на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests

Хочу спарсить фотографии товаров с этой страницы https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/muzhchinam/odezhda/bryuki-i-shorty?sort=popular&page=1&xsubject=4575

У wildberris клиент сайт рендеринг, я нашёл запрос с которого страница получает данные товаров https://catalog.wb.ru/catalog/men_clothes/catalog?appType=1&couponsGeo=12,3,18,15,21&curr=rub&dest=-1029256,-102269,-1278703,-1255563&emp=0&kind=1;11&lang=ru&locale=ru&page=1&pricemarginCoeff=1.0&reg=0&regions=68,64,83,4,38,80,33,70,82,86,75,30,69,22,66,31,48,1,40,71&sort=popular&spp=0&stores=117673,122258,122259,125238,125239,125240,6159,507,3158,117501,120602,120762,6158,121709,124731,159402,2737,130744,117986,1733,686,132043,161812,1193&subject=11;147;216;2287;4575&xsubject=4575

Вопрос в следующем, как мне автоматически узнавать ссылку на список товаров с описанием имея только ссылку на страницу товара https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/muzhchinam/odezhda/bryuki-i-shorty?sort=popular&page=1&xsubject=4575 ?

Знаю что такие сайты можно парсить с помощью selenium, но как такой парсинг можно реализовать на запросах ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Хочу спарсить фотографии"

```
import requests

page = 1
while True:
    resp = requests.get(f'https://catalog.wb.ru/catalog/men_clothes/catalog?curr=rub&lang=ru&locale=ru'
                        f'&sort=priceup&page={page}&xsubject=4575').json()
    page += 1
    prod = resp['data']['products']
    if not prod:
        break
    for model in prod:
        print('Бренд:', model['brand'])
        print('Цена:', model['salePriceU'] / 100, "руб.")

    index = model['id']
    id_c = str(index)[:-4]
    for num in range(1, model['pics'] + 1):
        img = f"https://images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/{id_c}0000/{index}-{num}.jpg"
        print(img)
        # img = f"https://images.wbstatic.net/big/new/{id_c}0000/{index}-{num}.jpg"
        # print(img)
        # img = f"https://images.wbstatic.net/c246x328/new/{id_c}0000/{index}-{num}.jpg"
        # print(img)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is hit-and-miss as sometimes the link will work, and sometimes you will receive a 418 HTTP error.

Comment: Сейчас должна работать функция или прикрыли этот ресурс (images.wbstatic.net)?

Comment: Сейчас вроде как все запросы по фото идут на basket-{VARIABLE}.wbbasket.ru, не знаю, может и на wbstatic тоже по-прежднему лежат фото, но у меня не получилось.